# Keras, method: fit, Error when checking input, about the shape

Tags: python, input, model, keras, shapes

I am building a model using TesnorFlow and Kras.

The shape of the input data is (345, 720, 120, 3). That is an array of images size 720x120.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: (x / 255.0) - 0.5, input_shape=(170,120,3)))   
model.add(Conv2D(24,(5,5),strides=(2,2),activation='relu'))
...

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, epochs=4)
```

For the last line 
I got an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lambda_1_input to have shape (170, 120, 3) but got array with shape (720, 120, 3)
```

The shape of input that is expected is the same as shape that I am giving to the fit function. What is the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question to add the code that you were running when you got that error message?

Comment: You should include the complete code, it is not obvious from the current information where the problem is. Single lines are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Such a stupid mistake.
I wrote in code input_shape=(170,120,3) instead of (720,120,3).

And in the result "expect to have shape (170, 120, 3) but got array with shape (720, 120, 3)" numbers 170 and 720 seemed the same for me?!

Model is successfully built and trained.